# Angular Jasmine $location $httpBackend: "Error: unexpected request"

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to unit test $urlRouterProvider.otherwise to show the url as whatever the user entered. However, every time I use $location in my unit test, I get this error

```
path default rerouting should go to error upon bad rerouting url FAILED
    Error: Unexpected request: GET public/templates/404.html
    No more request expected
        at $httpBackend (/Users/project/lib/angular-mocks.js:1207:9)
```

This is what I have in my config file:

```
$urlRouterProvider
        .when('', '/main')
        .when('/', '/main')
        .otherwise(function($injector){
            $injector.get('$state').go('404', {}, { location: false });
        });
```

And this is what I have as my spec.js file

```
describe('path', function(){

    var $rootScope, $state, $location, $injector, $templateCache, state;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$state_, _$injector_, _$location_, _$templateCache_, _$httpBackend_){
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
      $state = _$state_;
      $injector = _$injector_;
      $location = _$location_;
      $templateCache = _$templateCache_;
      $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

      $templateCache.put('public/templates/main.html', '');
      $templateCache.put('public/template/audio.html', '');
      $templateCache.put('public/template/404.html', '');

    }));

    describe('default rerouting', function(){
        it('should go to error upon bad url', function(){

            var badUrl = '/badUrlToTest';
            goTo(badUrl);
            expect($state.current.name).toEqual('404');
            expect($location.url()).toBe(badUrl);
        });
    });

    function goTo(url){
        $location.url(url);
        $rootScope.$digest();
    }
})
```

Using $state works just fine, and in the `goTo()` function $location seems to work, so why does using `$location.url()` (or `$location.path`) throw an error asking about $httpBackend when I'm not using an `$http.get()` request?

Answer (score 0):

There's no black magic, `$templateCache` is consistently used in both Angular and third-party libraries, it should work as expected if used properly.

Template cache entry is 'public/template/404.html'.

And requested template is 'public/template**s**/404.html'.